# Android. Нет изображеня после фотографирования

Tags: android

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == shotBtn) {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] ByteImg, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        addImg(ByteImg);
    }

public void addImg(byte[] ByteImg) {
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ByteImg);
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

    img.setImageBitmap(theImage);

    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Но в img ничего не записывается, изображение просто очищается(или удаляется, но маловероятно). Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

По вашему куску кода не ясно инициализировали вы камеру или нет, почитайте по ссылке, там и код рабочий есть.
[Работа с камерой в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112272/)

Comment: Я же говорил, что изображения нет именно после фотографирования. Я камеру уже инициализировал.